Can I deploy multiple heroku applications from same code base?
I have source controlled my client app, let's just call it TackleSoft
What I would like to do is deploy the TackleSoft to multiple heroku apps
In other words, I would like to have the following
TackleSoft source code version 1.0 - running as Joe's Bait shop application on heroku
TackleSoft source code version 1.4 - running as Bob's tackle application on heroku
Is this possible?  How can it be done?
I have read this SO article, but it doesn't address what I am asking
Deploy two separate heroku apps from same git repo
This Heroku post deals with the SAME app, but different environments for the app.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments
More questions based on comments:
How can I hook up git to multiple heroku applications ?

Sure, why wouldn't it be possible? It's not really any different from deploying to a single application. What problems are you encountering?

This isn’t a question about a programming problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris - I have no idea on how to accomplish it for MULTIPLE applications.... Heroku uses git to publish to an application ... how do you hook up git to multiple Heroku apps  ?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/102205/martin-bean - I disagree... I would like to find out how to do it... then program it to do it automatically - so it is a programming question... just the business requirements of a programming problem .
